# Creating a line chart in Google Sheets with non-contiguous ranges

Tags: google-sheets, charts

My chart has a dozen colums, but only three columns of interest..

- A, the date.
- B, a daily total.
- F, a rolling 14-day average of B.

When I define the data range as

```
Data!A4:A674,Data!B4:B674,Data!F4:F674
```

I get a line for the daily total (B), but there is no line at all for the 14-day average (F).  The chart works correctly when the columns are contiguous, but I'd like to be able to separate the columns for entry/readability purposes.

Comment: Kindly provide a sample spreadsheet and the expected output.

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result